# converting to DateTime from format y-z returns false

Tags: php, datetime

I have an old database with a column that contains expire dates, but not as dates but as integers that were generated like the following:

```php
$year = date("y") * 365;

$day = date("z");

// $duration is an int representing an amount of days e. g. 30 or 60
$expire = $year + $day + $duration;
```

Now I try to convert these integers back to dates with the following code:

```php
// $expire is the int that was selected from the database
$days = $expire % 365;

$year = ($expire - $days) / 365;

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('y-d', $year . '-' . $days);
```

For the first int (7759, which gives 94 for $days and 21 for $year) it works, but for the second one (7769 -> 104 and 21) $date is `false`. I don't understand why that happens, I would think, that `"104-21"` is a just as valid formatted string as `"94-21"`.

Comment: Instead of `y-d`, try `y-z`.

Comment: `d` only accepts 2 digits. it's meant to be 1-31 or 01-31, but you're gaming the system by going up to 99. 100 is right out. Guido is correct, you need `z` for the proper dates above 100. https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.createfromformat.php

Comment: Note that this format doesn't handle leap years properly, since it assumes all years are 365 days.

Comment: Thanks! In the title I used `z` and then in my code `d`... Thanks again, all of you!

Comment: @Barmar is there a function or best practice to handle leap years?

Comment: I think if you use 366 it should work.

Comment: @Barmar so just use 366 instead of 365? I am trying to think through it and see if there could be a case where that would return a wrong date, but I don't get it at the moment.

Comment: I think it should be OK. There are some values that correspond to nonexistent dates, but those will never be generated when starting from a real date.

Comment: @Barmar thank you! But I think, it probably won't work, because the dates are stored using 365 and then dividing by 366 will probably cause weird numbers

Answer (score 0):

The task and the proposed solution contain some problems.

1. A number derived from a date with

   $number = date("y") * 365 + date("z");

was created cannot be clearly assigned to the creation date. The date 2020-12-31 generates the number 7665. 2020 is a leap year with 366 days. However, the inverse transformation via date_create_from_format with the format 'y-z' returns the date 2021-01-01. A factor of at least 366 must be used (e.g. 1000) so that there are clear assignments.

2. When transforming back with date_create_from_format, the format '!y-z' should be used. Example for factor 1000:

   $date = date_create_from_format('!y-z',(int)($number/1000).'-'.$number%1000);

That "!" in format should not be omitted. Without the exclamation mark, the time is not set to 00:00, but to the current server time. When calculating expiry times without "!", Deviations can occur up to 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks! Sadly I can't undo the factor 365. I try to convert the dates stored like that in a database for a new database in which I will use just `date`s. But I'll use the exclamation mark.